# Set Content-Type for testing from Firefox

Tags: web-services, rest, firefox-addon, content-type

I need to do some REST service testing from Firefox where I set the Content-Type HTTP header to a specific value (to retrieve XML or JSON).

Is there a Firefox add-on that can do this?

Comment: Do you want to change the content type inside of firefox or just view it after it is changed elsewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to modify outgoing Request Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27936481/816213)

Comment: @SachinJain The question you linked to was asked 6 years later and deals with Chrome, not Firefox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's Modify Headers "... You can modify the user-agent string, add headers to spoof a mobile request (e.g. x-up-calling-line-id) ..."

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967

Answer (score 0):

The addon suggested in the accepted answer seems to not exist anymore.

There are some extensions for Firefox that permit to build HTTP/REST requests with specific headers or body content, like:

- [Resting](http://resting.owlcode.eu)
- [Rester](https://github.com/frigus02/RESTer)

Disclaimer: I'm the creator and maintainer of Resting