# Can I modify outgoing request headers with a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't see an answer to this in the [Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html), though maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

I want to intercept HTTP requests with a Chrome Extension, and then forward it on, potentially with new/different HTTP headers - how can I do that?

Comment: This is as close as I can find: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: Consider changing the accepted answer. The current accepted answer has become obsolete. The [newer answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274144/can-i-modify-outgoing-request-headers-with-a-chrome-extension/9143714#9143714) is correct.

Comment: If/when that answer is updated with an actual explanation and example of how to do it, I'll go ahead and mark it as the solution. A link alone is not an answer.

Comment: @PeterBoughton That just happened.

Comment: Also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29832996/748858

Comment: @mgilson It's not related. The link that you gave lets you copy the request as cURL and modify the headers manually and then send the request. OP wanted to do it right inside chrome with a chrome extension.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**PS:** I am the **author** of [Requestly](https://requestly.io?) - Chrome/Firefox extension to modify HTTP requests & responses.

It was certainly not possible when OP asked the question but now you can use [WebRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) with Manifest V2 and DeclarativeNetRequest API with Manifest V3 to write your own extension to modify Request & Response Headers.

### Manifest V2 code

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
        details.requestHeaders.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
  },
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
  ['blocking', 'requestHeaders' /* , 'extraHeaders' */]
  // uncomment 'extraHeaders' above in case of special headers since Chrome 72
  // see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle_footnote
);
```

Google Chrome is deprecating webRequest Blocking APIs in the Manifest V3. As per the [official statement](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/more-mv2-transition/) from Google on 28th Sep 2022, all extensions with Manifest v2 won't run on Chrome from June 2023 onwards. Here's an approach to Modify Request & Response headers with Manifest v3 - https://github.com/requestly/modify-headers-manifest-v3

### Manifest V3 Code:

#### rules.ts

```js
const allResourceTypes = 
    Object.values(chrome.declarativeNetRequest.ResourceType);

export default [
  {
    id: 1,
    priority: 1,
    action: {
      type: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.RuleActionType.MODIFY_HEADERS,
      requestHeaders: [
        {
          operation: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.HeaderOperation.SET,
          header: 'x-test-request-header',
          value: 'test-value',
        },
      ]
    },
    condition: {
      urlFilter: '/returnHeaders',
      resourceTypes: allResourceTypes,
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    priority: 1,
    action: {
      type: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.RuleActionType.MODIFY_HEADERS,
      responseHeaders: [
        {
          operation: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.HeaderOperation.SET,
          header: 'x-test-response-header',
          value: 'test-value',
        },
      ]
    },
    condition: {
      urlFilter: 'https://testheaders.com/exampleAPI',
      resourceTypes: allResourceTypes,
    }
  },
];
```

#### background.ts

```js
import rules from './rules';

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  removeRuleIds: rules.map((rule) => rule.id), // remove existing rules
  addRules: rules
});
```

The complete source code is available in the GitHub repo - https://github.com/requestly/modify-headers-manifest-v3

If you want to use an existing Chrome/Firefox/Edge Extension, you can use [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) which allows you to modify request and response headers. Have a look at this snapshot:

[image: Headers Rule Screenshot]

Comment: I would tone down the **`ADVERTISEMENT`**. 1) You should explicitly disclose it's your own creation, 2) Maybe a huge screenshot is out of place.

Comment: @Xan I have added PPS saying "I am the author". You are right I should have done this in first place. Snapshot may/may not be out of place, I am going to be it here. If you strongly feel it should not be there, remove it. I am just fine with it. Thanks for your input. I appreciate

Comment: Thanks blunderboy, and don't worry - your image is perfectly fine. You being the author was already self-evident from the repository link, and given that you first identified the API and showed example code (not to mention that it's an open source project), fussing over it being an "advertisement" is a pretty dumb thing to do.

Comment: Well I am happy - with Requestly I did my small test in 2 minutes which would have taken >20 minutes coding with the API.

Comment: +1 - Using it to debug ajax, setting to Modify Headers -> Add -> Request -> "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest"

Comment: @sachinjain024 I tried to use above code but it doesn't work for preflighted OPTIONS requests. Is there any way to make it work with OPTIONS request?

Comment: @BiJ From Chrome docs - `Use the chrome.webRequest API to observe and analyze traffic and to intercept, block, or modify requests in-flight.`. OPTIONS request is a preflight request and thus Chrome does not allow modification to it.

Comment: Um... this add-in doesn't actually work -- the sites can't see the headers you add, and if you look in the network console, you can see that the request headers were never added.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 There is a chrome bug due to which you will not be able to see the modifications in response headers. Moreover, you need to check if your Url match pattern is actually right now. open an issue on github.com/requestly/requestly-issues and I will look further into it.

Comment: I am able to do redirect/cancel requests etc with requestly but now add/delete/modify headers. Do I need to change settings as well to do it in chrome

Comment: @Vikram3891If you are modifying response headers, headers will be m odified by the extension but modifications are not visible in dev tool. This is a chrome bug. There is a list of headers which chrome does not allow you to modify. Please check this https://medium.com/@requestly_ext/list-of-headers-not-allowed-to-be-modified-by-chrome-extensions-c850b5c02fff. Reachout on requestly.extension@gmail.com for any issues

Comment: @sachinjain024 Yep. It seems so. had to use Firefox finally. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Where has this been all of my life?  Here's the link to Chrome & Firefox extension: http://www.requestly.in/

Comment: Look at the post below from @jossef-harush-kadouri for how to modify custom request headers using manifest version 3.

Comment: This does not work when we redirect a Url using `onBeforeRequest`, the redirected URL does not have headers present. Can someone let me know why does this happen?

Comment: @dqureshiumar If you look at the [webRequest lifecycle](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/webRequest#life_cycle_of_requests) onBeforeRequest is triggered before onBeforeSendHeaders so if you do a redirect then the redirection happens before sending the headers which makes sense. However, you can configure the headers on new URL (redirect URL) and the headers should be added to the new URL.

Comment: When I tried to send headers to the redirected URL, it went to the preflight call, but the headers did not go in the second call after preflight.

Comment: Could you please open an issue on github.com/requestly/requestly we can happily discuss it there, albeit it isn't related to requestly. We shouldn't make this comment list more noise as it has become already :)

Answer (score 12):

Modifying request headers ( https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest ) is supported in chrome 17.

Answer (score 6):

For extensions using **manifest version 3**, you can no longer use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.*`. The alternative is [chrome.declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/)

Make the following changes in your **manifest.json**:

```json
{
  ...
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],
  ...
}
```

- `"<all_urls>"` is for modifying all outgoing urls's headers. Restrict this for your scope of your work

Make the following changes in your **background.js**:

```js
// ...

const MY_CUSTOM_RULE_ID = 1

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [MY_CUSTOM_RULE_ID],
    addRules: [
        {
            id: MY_CUSTOM_RULE_ID,
            priority: 1,
            action: {
                type: "modifyHeaders",
                requestHeaders: [
                    {
                        operation: "set",
                        header: "my-custom-header",
                        value: "my custom header value"
                    }
                ]
            },
            condition: {
                "resourceTypes": ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
            },
        }
    ],
});
```

Result

[image]

Read the docs https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/

Comment: Just came across this while looking to add an update using manifest V3 myself. Added an upvote to this. Thanks, Jossef!

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at the right place, but intercepting HTTP requests does not exist yet, but the extension team is aware that it's a popular request and would like to get to it sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that starting from chrome 72, some headers are not allowed unless you add `extraHeaders` in `opt_extraInfoSpec`
So the above example in @sachinjain024's answer will look something like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
        details.requestHeaders.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
  },
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
  [ 'blocking', 'requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders']
);
```

For more info, check the documentation [Screenshot from the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1A8V.png) https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle_footnote

Answer (score 2):

You could install [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) extension and add headers:

[image]

Comment: how to remove header using this extension?

Comment: You can remove the headers that was added by you only.

Comment: 9/28/2023 warning: this extension will add google ads on webpage.

Comment: Yes, you can totally do that and then ModHeader is sneakingly injecting ads all over your google search result pages. Not cool.

Comment: this one now injects advertisements at Google search result page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) API which is now deprecated it allows you to modify request/response headers.
You can upgrade your extension to **Manifest V3** to be able to use [DeclativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) which also supports modifying request/response headers.

Or you can install [Inssman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inssman-modify-http-heade/ghlpdbkhlenlfiglgphledhfhchjfjfk) chrome extension.
It allows you to modify HTTP(S) request/response headers, reqirect and block request, return custom data like HTML/CSS/JS/JSON and more.  
And it is [open source](https://github.com/vvmgev/Inssman) project

## [Inssman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inssman-modify-http-heade/ghlpdbkhlenlfiglgphledhfhchjfjfk)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Chrome, FireFox and Edge.

Without installing any extension, only Edge allows me to replace the header "referer" and resend.