# Chrome Extensions accessing header information

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am on a mission to expand my knowledge and create an extension for chrome similar to how firephp works.  I want to integrate with my existing logging and debugging api within my framework and I want to be able to send these messages to the console.  Nothing really robust to start with just a way to send debug messages to the chrome console from php.

The plan is to send the messages via the headers and have the extension read those headers and interpret them.  I've been trying to find information on accessing the response headers and can't find any examples.  Some of the research has led me to possibly having to develop an NPAPI plugin to be able to accomplish this.

Before traveling down a dead end path I wanted to get the communities opinion here on which path I should be taking to find a solution.

Comment: I answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27936481/816213

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome cannot currently do this, but Google is working on it. A preliminary and incomplete implementation is in the development version of Chrome, or in Chrome Canary.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html

`onHeadersReceived`

http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/notifications-of-web-request-and-navigation

You can track progress here.

http://crbug.com/50943

Comment: this is an old answer, can we get an update? thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The web request api is now in stable and can be used to access header events.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/noaneddfkdjfnfdakjjmocngnfkfehhd) that does what you are trying to do. It uses cookies to communicate, from what I can tell.