# View and Set HTTP headers for Safari/Chrome

Tags: api, google-chrome, safari, http-headers

I'm testing an API and I would like to hit it with safari and see the raw json that's returned. The API requires a certain HTTP header be sent with every request. Is there a way in Safari or Chrome to set my http headers when visiting a URL?

Comment: I believe there are a few limitations to the core system that won't allow for extensions to be made that do this, I don't know if that has changed recently though...

Comment: Well, just don't get your hopes up... Chrome development is pretty damn rapid so maybe they fixed it and/or added options to do this.

Comment: You can also force an accept header by ending your URI with .json, or .xml, etc.

Comment: This answer could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/27936481/816213

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple Google Chrome apps that do this. One is called [Rest Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en&hc=search&hcp=main).
I actually found an app called [GraphicalHttpClient](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/graphicalhttpclient/id433095876?mt=12) in the Mac AppStore that's a lot easier and more enjoyable to use.

Comment: App Store item no longer available.

Comment: @christian-schlensker This answer has become irrelevant, both the links are dead. You may want to accept the latest answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68128919/816213

Answer (score 5):

Another popular chrome app for this is is [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)

Comment: Possible without using app? Would be nice to click logs and just quickly see JSON.

Answer (score 4):

The (currently experimental) WebRequest API lets you do view and modify headers: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html

It's pretty easy to view headers using `onSendHeaders`.

To edit headers, you'll need to block the request. This sample (from the docs linked to above) removes the User-Agent header from all requests:

```
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    delete details.requestHeaders['User-Agent'];
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
  },
  {},
["blocking"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Header Hacker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/phnffahgegfkcobeaapbenpmdnkifigc) will do the job on the Chrome browser and
[Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) on the FireFox browser.  Both of them allow to set custom HTTP Headers

Comment: I am looking for a simple extension which can replace **response** (not request) headers, but Header Hacker seems to be for requests only and Redirector seems to be able to do it, offering "Response Header" in the selection of replacement modes, but it does not seem to work. The WebRequest API should permit to replace response headers, but I am unable to develop a Chrome extension myself and do not have enough time to learn it. Other than using a local filtering proxy like Fiddler, I have no idea how to solve this in Chrome directly. Do you?

Comment: Update: Chrome extension Redirector works now and does what I need. There seemed to be a caching issue.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as my debugging proxy and set the header there.  See the "Add a request header" of the [FiddlerScript CookBook](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp).  This same solution would work with any browser.

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic
>   between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect
>   all HTTP(S) traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or
>   outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting
>   subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Modify Headers` extension in chrome.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Chrome you can use the **Modify Headers** rule in [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en)

Here's a screenshot of the Header Modification Rule

[image: Requestly Modify Headers Screenshot]

Requestly also has a feature that lets users share the rules with each other. Here's an example of a headers rule I created - https://app.requestly.io/rules/#sharedList/1624596871428-Stackoverflow-answer

To use it, follow the link and click on **Import List** to modify it as per your use case.

To modify headers in Safari, one can use [Requestly Desktop App](https://requestly.io/for-safari/)

Other References

- [Requestly](https://requestly.io)
- [Modify Headers](https://requestly.io/features/modify-request-response-headers)
- https://requestly.medium.com/how-to-modify-http-s-request-response-headers-in-chrome-firefox-safari-using-requestly-c1cd33610658

Comment: Can one use this tool without sending data into the cloud?

Comment: @TorstenBronger Yes you can. There is a setting to turn off syncing your data to their cloud. Just go to their app settings and turn of the `Enable Syncing` Toggle

Answer (score 0):

I know answer has already been chosen, however I thought I would share also:

EasyHTTP in Mac App Store. https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyhttp/id657224426?mt=12

It's free, easy to use and pretty good.

Comment: Its not free.,.