# Is there a Google Chrome extension to inject custom HTTP headers in each request?

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers

Firefox has [the "modifyheaders" plugin](http://www.garethhunt.com/modifyheaders/).  Is there anything like it for Google Chrome?

Comment: This question was asked when there was only an experimental API for Chrome extensions to access HTTP headers.  Since then the [WebRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) has been released, so now anyone can distribute extensions doing all sorts of manipulation of the headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension to Modify Outgoing request headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274144/can-i-modify-outgoing-request-headers-with-a-chrome-extension)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use the [WebRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

This was recently asked in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097502/view-and-set-http-headers-for-safari-chrome/7101360#7101360).

Comment: Thanks!  That means I have to write my own extension or get hold of one outside the typical distribution channels.  That's a good little project I guess, but I was hoping for something ready made.

Comment: The webRequest API is no longer experimental, and can now be found at: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html

Comment: Can you add an example of how to use the WebRequest API? Is it something that can be easily used from the console?

Comment: @DanDascalescu If you want to look at the example of how to use webRequest API, you can see here https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/blob/master/src/background/background.js#L148

Comment: This is not an answer to "is there an plugin like this"

Comment: Yeah, this answer definitely doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 45):

There's a bunch of nice extensions now!

Modifying headers for all requests

- [Modify Headers using Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-url-modify-heade/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa)
- [Modify Header Value](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-header-value-http/cbdibdfhahmknbkkojljfncpnhmacdek?hl=en)
- [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj)

Generic HTTP / REST clients

- [Postman REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) (Packaged App) - closed source, but used to be **[open source](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-chrome-extension-legacy)**
- [DHC - REST/HTTP API Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en) - closed source, but [faster and more robust than POSTman](https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/issues/793#issuecomment-68816737)
- [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) - **[open source](https://code.google.com/archive/p/chrome-rest-client/)**

Comment: As an absolute beginner REST Console and Postman are pretty heavy for me but I've picked up Dev HTTP Client in about 20/30 minutes. Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: ModHeader is nice and simple to use, also: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj

Comment: @Simon: ModHeader hasn't been updated in two years.

Comment: @DanDascalescu You can try Requestly - http://bit.ly/requestly-chrome-store. This is open source and I have tried my best to keep the UI simple.

Comment: Requestly worked great for my localhost testing. Thank you!

Comment: Just an update, Requestly is also available on Firefox. Download at http://requestly.in

Answer (score 0):

This plugin injects headers into all requests. [Modify Headers Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-headers-for-google/innpjfdalfhpcoinfnehdnbkglpmogdi)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score -1):

You can add/modify/delete headers site wise by using this tool called netspanner.

Netspanner-Modify Request Headers for Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/net-spanner/jlgbkimmjlnlenacfaclmmoaooicldnn

Comment: Please add some more details, Link may help but other details will give user more idea about your answer.