# Webrequest via post method return 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webrequest

like the tittle says, I was trying to make a request via post to some page. First using google developer tool, to check parameters for request, and I can figure out this (I am not completly sure if I put all correct parameters in my post string - check images for more information). I found many examples around www but no one works with this and I don't know what is wrong, I will aprecciate like always a bit help :).

**Request Headers**

[image: header_post]

**Form Data**

[image: form_data]

**This is my code:**

```
string email = "xxxxx";
string password = "xxxxx";

string LOGIN_URL = "https://intranet.cibertec.edu.pe/LoginBolsa/LoginBolsaCIB.aspx";

CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(
      webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
   );
string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
responseReader.Close();

string postString = string.Format("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$UserName={0}&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$Password={1}&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$LoginButton={2}&hdnOrigen={3}&hdnLinea={4}&Pagina_Principal={5}", email, password, "Ingresar", "bolsa", "I", "LoginBolsaCIB.aspx");


webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;


StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(postString);
requestWriter.Close();

responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
responseReader.Close();

Response.Write(responseData);
```

Comment: Possibly your request from Google Developer Tools gets called with SAME-ORIGIN but when you execute your code a different origin is present causing a problem with SAME-ORIGIN policy?

Comment: There is a way that I can set origin policy or some workaround?

Comment: You can only set the origin policy if you have control over the server-side.  Can you clarify whether or not you were able to sucessfully issue a POST using Google Developer Tools?

Comment: you mean that if same-origin policy is true or something like this, there is no way that i can make a request via post since other webpage?.

Comment: @DavidTansey , I don't sure how make a request with developer tools, so i follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248296/making-http-requests-using-chrome-developer-tools, but a error happens "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string(…)"

Comment: Look at the following for some guidance on issuing the POST request manually as a step towards being able to test your code confidently (without bad assumptions): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248296/making-http-requests-using-chrome-developer-tools .  I will also mention that I do not believe it is possible to issue a POST request manually using the Google Developer Tools in Chrome without the help of an add-in.

Comment: I'm using postman, and now I'm testing my request and same issue happens 404, not found :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because a missing `__ViewState` param. This params which is **hidden form field** is needed to attach for every Request.

```
int start = responseData.IndexOf("value=\"", responseData.IndexOf("name=\"__VIEWSTATE\""));
int end = responseData.IndexOf("/>", start);
string viewState = responseData.Substring(start + 7, end - start - 9);
string postString = string.Format("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$UserName={0}&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$Password={1}&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$LoginButton={2}&hdnOrigen={3}&hdnLinea={4}&Pagina_Principal={5}", email, password, "Ingresar", "bolsa", "I", "LoginBolsaCIB.aspx");
postString += String.Concat("&__VIEWSTATE=", viewState);
```

Comment: thank you bro, like you present it works, curiously i thought that when put cookies container was sending viewstate too, why this doesn't happen?.

Comment: Theres no way to get viewstate in a more "elegant" form?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla, There is, by using 3rd Party like `HtmlAgilityPack`, but i wanted to keep it simple without complicating your code. Additionally, we can make the current extraction with a `Generic Tag Extractor` like function. `__ViewState` is a input type and belong to the data that should be send as part of the `Http Content` while `Cookies` are part of the `Http Headers`