# Is it safe to do case insensitive comparison on AppEngine headers?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, webapp2, google-app-engine-python

AppEngine makes some guarantees about specific headers in tasks.  Specifically, a set of headers such as [`X-AppEngine-QueueName`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers#reading_request_headers) are not able to be set by a user.

> These headers are set internally by App Engine: If an external user request attempts to set these headers, they are removed. Therefore, if your request handler finds any of these headers in a request, that task queue request is guaranteed to be valid.

It appears that both web frameworks provided by GAE (`webapp` and `webapp2`) have `Request` objects that inherit from `webob.Request`.  Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, `webob.Request` only exposes the headers in a [case-insensitive way](http://docs.webob.org/en/stable/api/request.html#webob.request.BaseRequest.headers).  Does AppEngine guarantee that a user is unable to provide those request headers in a case-insensitive way?

In other words, can a user set a `X-AppEngine-Queuename` header on the request and have it passed through (at which point, `webob` would not be able to distinguish between that header and the real one provided by GAE)?

In the `webapp2` framework, how do I guarantee that my request originated as a task and not as the result of a malicious user?

Comment: Maybe I can assume that this is OK because HTTP headers are case-insensitive according to [RFC2616: 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/748858)?

Comment: I tried with setting `X-AppEngine-QueueName` header along with one of my request. On the handler, it automatically turns into `X-Appengine-Queuename` as one of the header key.

Comment: You can protect the worker service's handler by setting `admin: true` in the worker.yaml file.

Comment: @AvinashRaj -- That's because webob [normalizes using title-case](https://github.com/Pylons/webob/blob/master/webob/headers.py#L107).  You're right about `admin: true` -- That is one way to lock down these handlers specifically.  Unfortunately, headers added by admin don't get stripped, so those tests are a bit hard to do :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've done some experimentation and it appears that GAE does indeed sanitize the headers in a case-insensitive manner (as would be expected based on [RFC 7230 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2)).

For anyone interested in my testing methodology, I first added the following logging statements to my webapp2 request handler:

```
logging.info('request headers: %s', self.request.headers.items())
logging.info('request env: %s', list(self.request.headers.environ)
```

I then navigated to my site in chrome with the development tools open.  I found the request for the handler that I had modified in the "Network" tab.  [Right clicking this gives the option to copy the request as cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29832996/748858) so I did that and pasted it into a shell script.  I then modified the copied request to remove all cookies (I don't want GAE identifying me as an app-admin) and to add a `x-appengine-queuename: boom` header.  I submitted the curl request and took a look in my logs.  There was no `x-appengine-queuename` header.  I also added a `x-appengine-mgilson: test` header and that header was passed through.

From the implementation side, the environment has all uppercase headers (e.g. `self.request.headers.environ` has all upper-case keys with a few exceptions that all start with `wsgi.` -- like `wsgi.run_once`).  The headers are all prefixed by `HTTP_` -- I'm guessing that this is part of some standard somewhere... `webob` strips the `HTTP_` and title-cases the rest of the header name when it looks up a value in `self.request.headers` (presumably to comply with the previously mentioned RFC, and to provide a nicer human-readible version).