# automatic crawling web site

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I got help from here to crawl on law.go.kr with the code below. 
I'm trying to crawl other websites like http://lawbot.org, http://law.go.kr, https://casenote.kr. 
But problem is that I have no understanding of html...
I understood all the code and how to get html address for the code below but it's different on other websites... 
I want to know how to use the code below to crawl other web pages.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Using request get 50 items from first page. pg=1 is page number, outmax=50 items 
per page
    response = requests.post(
        "http://law.go.kr/precScListR.doq=*&section=evtNm&outmax=79329&pg=1&fsort=21,10,30&precSeq=0&dtlYn=N")

    # Parse html using BeautifulSoup
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # Go through all pages and collect posts numbers in items
    items = []
    for i in range(1, 2):
        # Get all links
        links = page.select("#viewHeightDiv .s_tit a")
        # Loop all links and collect post numbers
        for link in links:
            # Parse post number from "onclick" attribute
            items.append(''.join([n for n in link.attrs["onclick"] if n.isdigit()]))

    # Open all posts and collect in posts dictionary with keys: number, url and text
    posts = []
    for item in items:
        url = "http://law.go.kr/precInfoR.do?precSeq=%s&vSct=*" % item
        response = requests.get(url)
        parsed = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        text = parsed.find('div', attrs={'id': 'contentBody'}).text     #전문 저장 
'id': 'contentBody', 제목제외 저장 'class': 'pgroup'
        title = parsed.select_one("h2").text
        posts.append({'number': item, 'url': url, 'text': text, 'title': title})

        with open("D://\LAWGO_DATA/" + item + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
            f.write(text)
```

Comment: @Sers how to use code on http://lawbot.org.     for item in items:
        url = "http://law.go.kr/precInfoR.do?precSeq=%s&vSct=*" % item ***this part***
        response = requests.get(url)
        parsed = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        text = parsed.find('dd', attrs={'class': 'media list-group-item'}).text 
        title = parsed.select_one("h2").text***this part***
        posts.append({'number': item, 'url': url, 'text': text, 'title': title})

Comment: @Sers other webs doesnt have body on curled address and no clue with Lawbot

Comment: webs not the same and can have different requests/parameters. `precInfoR.do?precSeq=%s&vSct=` parameters is only for particular web posted in previous question. You can find helpful information in [replay-a-network-request-in-curl](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/replay-a-network-request-in-curl)

Comment: @Sers yeah i know that so it is possible to use ur code on lawbot.org if i can find right urls for the lawbot.org right?

Comment: Yes, you can with small changes like selectors

Comment: @Sers  links = page.select("#list-group media-list media-list-stream mb-4 .media-title a")and text = parsed.find('dd', attrs={'class': 'media list-group-item'}).text
        title = parsed.select_one("span").text
i changed except for the item in items url... any clue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more example for [lawbot.org](http://lawbot.org):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://lawbot.org'
search_url = base_url + '/?q=유죄'

response = requests.get(search_url)

page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
lastPageNumber = int(page.select_one("li.page-item:not(.next):nth-last-child(2)").text)

casesList = []

for i in range(1, lastPageNumber + 1):
    if i > 1:
        response = requests.get(search_url + "&page=" + str(i))
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    cases = page.select("div.panre_center > ul.media-list li.panre_lists")
    for case in cases:
        title = case.findChild("h6").text
        caseDocNumber = case.findChild(attrs={"class": "caseDocNumber"}).text
        caseCourt = case.findChild(attrs={"class": "caseCourt"}).text
        case_url = base_url + case.findChild("a")['href']

        casesList.append({"title": title, "caseDocNumber": caseDocNumber, "caseCourt": caseCourt, "case_url": case_url})
        # print("title:{}, caseDocNumber:{}, caseCourt:{}, caseUrl:{}".format(title, caseDocNumber, caseCourt, case_url))

for case in casesList:
    response = requests.get(case["case_url"])
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    body = page.find(attrs={"class": "panre_body"}).text
    print(body)
```

Comment: gives me this error ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/python_study1/PROJECT2/LAWBOT.py", line 16, in <module>
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, requests.post(url + "&page=" + str(i + 1)))
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\ai_study\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 189, in __init__
    if features is None or len(features) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: i did.. hm..  so that gives me all the titles on the pages right? it only gives one.. and then i can do items like the code before?

Comment: Will give all titles from all pages. You can get anything from responses using beautifulsoup and query

Comment: its keep saying   if features is None or len(features) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: i want to get all the values of caseDocNumber and caseCourt to get all the url for the post but it's not working...i dont know where i did wrong and i have to wait 4more days to post new question... save me @Sers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189114/discussion-between-kwanhee-hwang-and-sers).