# GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found),actually am calling POST but getting GET

Tags: node.js, express

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

// app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
//   res.send('Hello World!')
// })

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

*its a normal express post request but when am calling it am getting following error

localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

but get(),all() methods are working fine

Comment: How are you calling the post endpoint? Do you hit it via postman or browser?

Comment: i am hitting via browser

Comment: You cannot send a POST request by hitting from browser, all requests are of GET type when you hit manually in browser. You should check out postman for sending other request types: https://www.postman.com/

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to send post request from browser??

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248296/making-http-requests-using-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requests that you hit manually in browser address bar are of GET type. To send POST or any other request types you should be using postman. See - https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/sending-the-first-request/