# Error running javascript fetch in Chrome devtools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch, google-chrome-devtools, google-developers-console

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248296/making-http-requests-using-chrome-developer-tools) SO post I should be able to run a fetch request from Chrome devtools console. In fact, if I click the button in the post answer, it works.

However, if I try to execute the very same code in the console, it doesn't work.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

[image]

What's missing?

Comment: May be internet connection. Search `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` in browser search bar and validate the response

Comment: I can't reproduce this-- I'm able to run this from my console and get a response.  You may probably need to provide more context/information...

Comment: @brk It works on the browser

Comment: @AlexanderNied There is no context. I am just doing what in the picture

Comment: @FrancoTiveron - works in the console here too (from melbourne, australia)

Comment: Are you behind a VPN?  Are you on an enterprise machine that might have security software installed?  What site are you on when you are running this in the console?  Is this Windows, MacOs, or Ubuntu?  Do you have any browser plugins installed, perhaps any specific to the devtools?  I'm just looking for anything that could be causing this because I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Any ideas on what I could look at?

Answer (score 6):

Don't know why, however it depends on the current domain the browser is:

Home page:

[image]

After browsing a page (whatever page):

[image]

My guess would be that in the first case there is not an established source domain, but a better error description would help.

Comment: Lol nice hint. Somehow it resolves problem

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. If I had to guess it is to do with https. When no website is open it is effectively making https request from a non-https website hence it gets rejected