# make a web request to "about:internet" via cmdline (ping/curl/powershell, etc.)

Tags: python, powershell, curl, ping

so we are seeing a lot of web requests sent to "about:internet" in our product, but no idea how they are generated

I mapped a legit IP address to `about:internet` in the `hosts` file, but `ping about:internet` doesn't seem to work.

```
C:\Users\admin>ping about:internet
Ping request could not find host about:internet. Please check the name and try again.
```

but if I ping the IP address directly, it works good

```
C:\Users\admin>ping 100.705.033.940

Pinging 100.705.033.940 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 100.705.033.940: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from 100.705.033.940: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 100.705.033.940: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 100.705.033.940: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 100.705.033.940:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 0ms
```

Hoping someone would know how to send a web request [via cmdline] to `about:internet`. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `about` pages are not resolved by domain service. Instead, those are built-ins of browsers.

References:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/232352/what-are-all-the-about-pages-in-internet-explorer.
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme.

What this means is that it is impossible to make such requests from CLI. You will have to at least your browser's console to do this.

---

I did not succeed in using browser console to do this though. It might worth a try if you can find the requests that you see that your product send, and then use those URLs. Check this: [Making HTTP Requests using Chrome Developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248296/making-http-requests-using-chrome-developer-tools).