# HTTP proxy to modify outgoing HTTP requests on fly

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, httprequest, http-proxy, mitmproxy

I need to modify all outgoing HTTP requests from my browser on fly.

1) Is there some python package I can use for the same? I am able to capture the outgoing requests using scapy, but not able to modify on the fly.

2) Can I modify the outgoing HTTP request in chrome extension? Do Chrome provide some API that can help?

Comment: Checking this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274144/can-i-modify-outgoing-request-headers-with-a-chrome-extension), it is mentioned in the answer that this was supported. You can visit the documentation for [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Answer (score 2):

You can set your browser's proxy to mitmproxy and use [mitmproxy scripting](https://mitmproxy.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.2/scripting/overview.html) to modify the output traffic.

You do not need Chrome extension to achieve that. You can load your own script.py like this:

```
mitmdump -s your_script.py
```

There are lots of examples your can check from [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/tree/master/examples) GitHub page.