# CORS in POST request chrome extension development

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I make POST request from extension but It's automated add origin: chrome extension://oinaehobmloogbkdgopkbeggjfnoobho into header request

I want to change origin to the same origin server I sent request
example:
I request to facebook.com
I want to set Origin : https://www.facebook.com

I set permission varible in manifest.json like this but still not working:

"permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "notifications",
        "tabs",
        "cookies",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "storage"
      ]

[image]

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your code is lacking a [mcve]

Comment: Just setting the permissions won't change this behavior. You need to add `webRequest` to permissions and actually replace the Origin header in your background script as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541729).