# browser extension for stored private/public key

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I'm thinking of making a passwordless and Ulta simple web server.

The basic idea is that to make changes (post, add pull requests, etc) you first email (or otherwise communicate) your public key to the admin. You then load your private key into a tiny browser extension and your POST requests include your signature.

The motivation is I want to make it easy to interact for non-browsers as well (i.e. small command line app) and get away entirely from user names / passwords / etc.

Is there such a concept out there? Is such a thing as easy as I think it is (very easy)? I'd like to not reinvent the wheel if there is a simple standard that already does this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should be possible with something like

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27936481/1036670

I'd still like to know if anyone has done this already.